# reading hex data from file fscanf format compile time warning

Tags: c, formatting, hex

I'm reading some data from a file. The format is stated tobe

> ASCII text with UNIX-style
>   line-endings, a series of 32-bit
>   signed integers in hexadecimal.

e.g

```
08000000
```

I'm using fscanf to read in this data.

```
long data_size;

FILE *fp;
fp=fopen("test01.bin", "r"); // open for reading
if (fp==0) {cerr << "Error openeing file"<<endl; return 1;}

fscanf(fp, "%x", &data_size);
```

Everything runs ok with my test file but I get the compile-time warning,

```
warning: format ‘%x’ expects type ‘unsigned int*’, but argument 3 has type ‘long int*’
```

however a hex value is unsigned and is being cast to a long dose this matter? As long will take the most significant bit as notifying the sign? Or will I end up with problems? Or am I well off the mark in my understanding?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should support the same pointer type as the warning states, or else you will run into serious troubles if you want to port your code to other architectures (e.g: 64 bit architectures) where `long` has a different size than `int`. This is especially tricky if you are using pointers. (I once had a bug originating from **exactly** this problem)

Just use `int data_size` and you will be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the warning, this will be run on different machines. So even though the hex value is 32 bits and int is 16 bit I am ok using int data_size ? (I understand long is 32 bit?).

Comment: @Tommy, you probably want to take a look at `int32_t` type from `<stdint.h>`. It's guaranteed that `(u)intN_t` are N bits long: http://linux.die.net/man/3/int32_t

Comment: Unfortunately the size of `long` and `int` depend on the systems architecture. But I think on a 32bit operating system, `int` and `long` are equally sized 32 bits. Only on 16bit (16 and 32bit) and 64bit (32 and 64?) system this might cause troubles. I am really unsure about the numbers.

A **Hex** string itself has no "length", you could encode any number in a hex-string. Of course an overflow can occur if the number does not fit into the variable. I guess an error will be set in that case.

Comment: Interesting thanks. Perhaps I should initially read the data in as a char array then cast to a int32_t data type suggested by Angle if there is an atoi equivalent for int32. Thanks for the pointer Angel.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `%x` requires an `unsigned int *` to read the value in, but you have a `long *`. `<stdint.h>` header provides value types with fixed length, and `<inttypes.h>` defines corresponding macros for use with `printf`, `scanf`, and their derivatives. I think it'll be better for you to `fscanf` the data into an `int32_t` variable using the macro provided by `<inttypes.h>`:

```
#include <inttypes.h>

...

int32_t data_size;
fscanf(fp, "%" SCNx32, &data_size);
```